# How can I stop another copy of Knockout.js ViewModel from being created each time I try to update the view?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm trying to update my ViewModel each time an [add] link is clicked and another textbox is added to the below HTML:

```
<a href="" data-bind="click: addItem">[add]</a>
 <div id="items">
     <input class="item" type="text" data-bind="value: searchRequest.Items[0].ItemName"/>
 </div>
```

My ViewModel looks like the following:

```
$(function () {
    var ViewModel = function() {
         var self = this;
         this.searchRequest = {
             Items: [{
                        ItemName: ko.observable("")
                     }] 
         };
             this.addItems = function() { 
                 var htmlToInsert = '<input class="items" type="text" data-bind="value:  searchRequest.Items[' + self.searchRequest.Items.length.toString() + '].ItemName"/>';

                $(htmlToInsert).insertAfter('.item');

                self.searchRequest.Items.push({
                    ItemName: ko.observable(""),
                });

                ko.applyBindings(self, document.getElementById("items"));
             }
         }
});
```

So, basically it works fine except for another copy of ViewModel being created each time an [add] link is clicked. This results in the textboxes being duplicated. So, when I have two textboxes and click [add], two more textboxes are added instead of one. So, I see 4 textboxes instead of 3. When I click [add] again - 4 more textboxes appear. When I enter a value into any of the newly appeared textboxes, it gets reflected in the other textboxes that appeared with it. Basically, addItems function is invoked by each ViewModel, resulting in multiple textboxes being added. I tried commenting

```
ko.applyBindings(self, document.getElementById("items"));
```

out, but it didn't help.

How can I fix this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you put together a jsfiddle to show your problem? I'm not able to repro your issue whit the code in your post, because you haven't show how do you create your `ViewModel` and how do you can the main `applyBindings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `knockout` but aren't using it is features. You don't need manually create `textboxes`, `knockout` will do it for you. Make `Items` array - `observableArray` and just push items to it:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.searchRequest = {
        Items: ko.observableArray([{
            ItemName: ko.observable("")}])
    };

    self.addItem = function() {
        self.searchRequest.Items.push({
            ItemName: ko.observable(""),
        });
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

And then render `Items` using `foreach` binding:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: addItem">[add]</a>
<div data-bind="foreach: searchRequest.Items" id="items">
    <input class="item" type="text" data-bind="value: ItemName"/>
</div>
```

Here is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/L8Mru/

Comment: Thank you so much, brother. That did it. As you can tell, I'm pretty new to Knockout.js. I had spent so much time on this yesterday and was thinking about all kinds crazy workarounds for this isuue, but I knew there was an easier way. Again, Огромное спасибо!!!